# Date/Time range computaion in SSRS

Tags: date, reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I have sets of date/time range values, each set came from different column ("FROM" and "TO")

examples:

- FROM: June 6, 2016 7:00 AM; TO: June 6, 2016 5:00 PM
- FROM: June 6, 2016 8:00 PM; TO: June 7, 2016 6:00 AM

I want to get how many minutes of each set falls to 3:00 PM - 2:00 AM (next day) or "OFF PEAK HOURS", like this

[image]

for the example above, I want to get the number of minutes between 3PM - 2AM next day.

- on the first row, from 7AM-5PM, two hours is included to my 3PM-2AM range criteria, which is 3PM-5PM (2 hours) . Thats why I got 120 mins.
- on the second row, from 8PM-6AM next day, two hours is included to my 3PM-2AM range criteria, which is 8PM-2AM (6 hours). Thats why I got 360 mins.

see this graph for reference:

[image: Click here for the graph]

I want to count the number of minutes falls during "OFF PEAK HOURS"-shaded in orange/tan.

Is it doable in expression?
Thank you in advance.

Please note that I am using fetchXML for the query.

Comment: How is possible that from 7 AM to 5 PM have passed 120 minutes?

Comment: I think, he wants to count minutes from 3pm-2am so it we take example of first row then -  `June 6, 2016 5:00 PM` - then it would count after 3pm-5pm so it is 2 hours. that's why it is 120 mins. but same calculation goes wrong with 2nd row so I am also confused.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i updated this thread. Hope i did explain it well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the table you put in the question is wrong and it is only an example, I think you can get the spent minutes between two dates by using this expression:

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute,
Fields!From.Value,
Fields!To.Value
)
```

Example:

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute,
CDATE("2016-06-06 07:00:00 AM"),
CDATE("2016-06-06 05:00:00 PM")
)
```

The above example returns 600. 10 hours by 60 minutes. `DateDiff` function returns the specified date/time interval of time between two specified dates.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i updated this thread. Hope i did explain it well. Thank you.

Comment: What is the structure of your dataset?

Comment: <fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">
 <entity name="fp_dailytimerecord" >
  <attribute name="fp_shiftfrom"/> 
  <attribute name="fp_shiftto"/>
  <attribute name="fp_name"/>
  <filter type="and">
   <condition attribute="statecode" value="0" operator="eq"/>
   <condition attribute="fp_date" value="@DateFrom" operator="on-or-after"/>
   <condition attribute="fp_date" value="@DateTo" operator="on-or-before"/>
  </filter>
 </entity>
</fetch>